# The best way to display an image in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an image which I want the user to change size when it pinch and after it pinch the user can move around the image

what is the best way to do that in xamarin froms
would be happy to a simple code example

here what I have tried but ot doesn't do the best of work:

Xaml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ComplexInstructionApp.ShowProgram"
         Title="תוכנית הלימוד שלנו">

   <ContentPage.Content>


</ContentPage.Content>


<Image x:Name="IMI" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  
VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Image>


</ContentPage>
```

and here is the C# below:

```
public partial class ShowProgram : ContentPage
{

    private double currentScale = 1;
    private double startScale = 1;
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;

    public ShowProgram(string txt)
    {                 
        InitializeComponent();
        switch (txt)
        {
            case "קובני":
                Title = "קובני";
                IMI.Source = "Cuben_Expend.png";
                break;

            case "קובני מצומצם":
                Title = "קובני מצומצם";
                IMI.Source = "Cuben_short.png";
                break;
            case "אל איי":
                Title = "אל איי";
                IMI.Source = "LA_Expend.png";
                break;
            case "אל איי מצומצם":
                Title = "אל איי מצומצם";
                IMI.Source = "LA_short.png";
                break;
            case "בצ'אטה":
                Title = "בצ'אטה";
                IMI.Source = "bachata.png";
                break;
            case "זוק":
                Title = "זוק";
                IMI.Source = "zouk.png";
                break;
        }


        var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += (s, e) =>
        {

            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
            {
                // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
                // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
                startScale = Content.Scale;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
            {
                // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the X pixel coordinate.
                double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
                double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
                double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
                double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
                double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
                double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

                // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
                double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
                double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

                // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
                Content.TranslationX = Clamp1(targetX, -Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
                Content.TranslationY = Clamp1(targetY, -Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

                // Apply scale factor.
                Content.Scale = currentScale;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
            {
                // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            }
        };
        Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
    }

    public  double Clamp1(double self, double min, double max)
    {
        return Math.Min(max, Math.Max(self, min));
    }







}
```

Comment: So, what do you have tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "_it does not do the best of work_"? What is the problem with the code?

Comment: you cannot move left or right after you zoom in. your cannot move aournt the image while you zoom in. also you cannot focus.